# Linq to SQL. How to read results by row and without putting all records into memory

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to read Linq to SQL result by row, without puting whole result to memory? Something like [OleDB DbDataReader.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_Read).

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy, yes I did, and got OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Could you post the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. LINQ defers its execution by default. I.e., the items are only read from the source as enumeration takes place. If you are using `foreach` directly (without calling `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` first) the result set will not be stored in memory as a whole.

However, since object tracking stores information for each object being loaded, you can still get a memory overflow for very big result sets. To avoid this, set `context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;`. As a side effect, you will also notice a performance gain.

Comment: So can you explain me why this code generates OutOfMemoryException (table has more then 7 billion rows)
foreach (var pay in db.Pays/*.Where(p => true)*/)
{
    int id = pay.ClientID;
}

Comment: Try setting `.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false` on the context, otherwise a tracking information will be stored for each item. This will also speed up execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's the goal of [Deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution) in LinQ .Use Entity Framework and you can query using linQ and IQueryable.

Comment: I can't use EF, project uses Linq to SQL. So when I'm iterating through IQueryable result I get OutOfMemoryException